# Display List in MAUI Blazor App after json deserialization

Tags: blazor, maui

Display List in MAUI Blazor App  after json deserialization, List is not displayed in MAUI Blazor App while the jsonString is displayed. The webapi is returning value when I deserialize  to list it is giving error also cannot debug the code.Please suggest on this.
I checked the List and json have same schema.
https://github.com/KalyanAllam/RateApp/

```
@page "/"
@using System.Text;
@using System.Net.Http.Headers;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@using RateApp.Models;

@jsonString


@Questions

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           
            <th>DaysBegin</th>
            <th>DaysEnd</th>
            <th>Interest</th>
            <th>SrInterest</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (InQuestion inques in Questions)
{
    // Pass the Dto properties to the component
    <InQuestion  DaysBegin="@inques.DaysBegin" DaysEnd="@inques.DaysEnd"   Interest="@inques.Interest"   SrInterest="@inques.SrInterest"/>
}
</tbody>
</table>

@code {
     public class InQuestion
    {




        public int No { get; set; }

        public int DaysBegin { get; set; }

        public int DaysEnd { get; set; }

        public decimal Interest { get; set; }

        public decimal SrInterest { get; set; }

    }
     



    public string codex; public string  jsonString ; public bool statcode;
     List<InQuestion> Questions = new List<InQuestion>();
     public int number; int totalquestions;
     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {



        string jwturl = "https://quizapijwt.azurewebsites.net/api/";



        using (var client1 = new HttpClient())
        {
            

              
                client1.BaseAddress = new Uri(jwturl);

                client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                 HttpResponseMessage response = await client1.GetAsync("RateCards");
             
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api
                      jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                     
                       
                       
                       Questions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InQuestion>>(jsonString);



                }
            }
            

   
   
        
    }
  }
```

Comment: "it is giving error" - this is not helpful.  What **specific** error is it giving?

Comment: When I display questions,  it displays this System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RateApp.Pages.Index+InQuestion]

Comment: Here is github link https://github.com/KalyanAllam/RateApp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was caused by `@Questions`. And you want to

> Display List in MAUI Blazor App after json deserialization

You can delete the `@Questions` and `@jsonstring` and display data in the foreach loop. Such as:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           
            <th>DaysBegin</th>
            <th>DaysEnd</th>
            <th>Interest</th>
            <th>SrInterest</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (InQuestion inques in Questions)
{
    // Pass the Dto properties to the component
            <tr>
                <td>@inques.DaysBegin</td>
                <td>@inques.DaysEnd</td>
                <td>@inques.Interest</td>
                <td>@inques.SrInterest</td>
            </tr>
        }
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the result image:

[image]